# sql-connect with Ivy

Tags: helm, ivy, sql-mode, sql-interactive-mode

I've switched from helm to Ivy and mostly everything works, but today I noticed that connecting to databases with `sql-connect` doesn't work anymore. I have the following in the variable `sql-connection-alist`

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
  '(("dev" (sql-product 'postgres)
     (sql-database "testdb")
     (sql-user "testuser")
     (sql-server "localhost")
     (sql-password ""))))
```

which was sufficient under helm and vanilla emacs for running `M-x sql-connect` and connecting to a database. When I run it under Ivy though, I get a prompt that looks similar to this:

```
0    Connection:
```

When I type `dev` and press `<enter>` or try to tab complete, the prompt changes to

```
0    Connection (match required): dev
```

and I can't get any further. The `match required` part is red, indicating an error, but I don't know how to get past this point. If it were a tab-completion, I'd at least expect typing "dev" and pressing `<enter>` to be sufficient, but I get the same error.

What do I need to do to connect to a database using Ivy in emacs?

Comment: This is something that was working with earlier versions of ivy -- I've been meaning to file an ivy issue for this problem. I've hit this a couple times and have just done M-x ivy-mode to turn ivy off (then back on) around a sql-connect command.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1112 for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue in ivy, so I filed it: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1112.

And it's already been fixed!